# Incorporating bridges into DEM for route profiles

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, elevation, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

I'm making transit route elevation profiles to see how the topography changes over the course of certain bus routes.

The data I'm working with:

- DEM of the study area
- GTFS tables

I'm having no issues making the elevation profile. Using the *Interpolate Shape* tool, I'm inputting my DEM as the surface and my bus routes as features. This generates a topography of the route, however, I'm having issues with bridges or raised roadways. Because a DEM is bare-earth, it doesn't include any of the bridges the bus routes take. I have tried a DTM of the study-area but this doesn't include bridges either.

How can I incorporate bridges into the DEM so that my route profiles don't dip 30-40meters each time they pass over water?

Is this a question of "burning" the route data into the DEM?

If so, how should I go about doing this?

I don't normally work with elevation data so I'm slightly out of my comfort zone here.

Comment: Depending on your study area, you may be able to obtain a Digital Surface Model (DSM), rather than a Digital Terrain Model (DTM). A DSM will include bridges.

Comment: @Matt I've tried a DSM but I'm getting extremely spiked profiles because of how that data works. It definitely includes bridges so that's a plus! Any ideas how to maintain a somewhat even elevation profile without massive spikes from say tree canopy over a road?